# load js file as string and exetute it after changing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need load my JS file, make some changes ad execute it after that

script is on the another domain

i'm trying like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/file.js",
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
        q: "query"
    },
    success: function( result ) {
        console.log( result );
    }
});
```

i haven't receive result

and like this

```
 $.getScript("http://example.com/file.js?q=query", function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
     console.log(data); // Data returned
     console.log(textStatus); // Success
     console.log(jqxhr.status); // 200 });
```

but data is undefined

Comment: You cannot make a cross-domain script request. It will need to be stored on the same domain as the originating request.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I believe we can make CORS with `jsonp`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , i'm making cross-domain request, but script is executing instantly, or have no result, i need get it's data into string